# UITableView reorder with tap within table

Tags: ios, uitableview

A question for those who have used a UITableView in the past

I am currently using a UITableView in edit mode and I have the following data source / delegate methods implemented

- `(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath
  //which tells me where the cell has been moved to`
- `(NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView targetIndexPathForMoveFromRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)sourceIndexPath toProposedIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)proposedDestinationIndexPath
  //which tells me where it may be moved`

What I want to achieve:
when I pick a cell and reorder it, the cell should move up and down in the table view **only** while the finger is within the table view. Which means if I start from within the table view and move outside it, the cell should snap back in position and not let me reorder the cell.

The problem is that there is no way to find out (that I know of) where my finger is while the reorder is being performed. If I can find out where the finger is then it might be possible to achieve this.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath function.  HTH.